# Display information from MySQL Database on page using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-deployment

I have a database called test.  In it there is a table called people.  People has 4 fields: fname, lname, age, city.   I have a page with a form where people can enter in data.

```
<?php
include('header.php');
?>

<body>
<form action="getinformation.php" method="post" id="getinformation">
<div id="header">
<h1><strong>Search For Data</h1></strong>
</div>
<div id="main">
<table border="0" width="75%">
        <tr>
            <td align="right" width="10%">First Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" size="20" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="right" width="10%">Last Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" size="20" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="right" width="10%">Age: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age" size="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="right" width="10%">City: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="20" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" />
</div>
</body>

<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```

When the submit button is clicked it will send the data to another page named getinformation.php.

```
<?php
require_once('model.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE";

if (isset ($POST_fname) {
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$query = $query . " fname = " . $fname . " AND" }
if (isset ($POST_lname) {
$lname = $_POST['lname']; 
$query = $query . " lname = " . $lname . " AND" }
if (isset ($POST_age) {
$age = $_POST['age']; 
$query = $query . " age = " . $age . " AND" }
if (isset ($POST_city) {
$city = $_POST['city']; 
$query = $query . " city = " . $city . " AND" }

$query = rtrim($query, " AND");
?>
<div id=/"header/">
<h1><strong>This is the information you requested</h1></strong>
</div>
<div id=/"main/">
<?php
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$products = $statement->fethAll();
$statement->closeCursor();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product['fname'] . " " . $product['lname'] . " | " . $product['age'] . " | " . $product['city'] . '<br />';
?>
</div>
<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```

I get an error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\testwebpage\Model\getinformation.php on line 6
```

I have had this problem before with my isset function but aside from that working I'm wondering if the rest of the code looks fine (assuming isset worked perfectly)

Comment: Missing a heck of a lot of `;`'s

Comment: huh many syntax error, just one: change `isset ($POST_fname)` to `isset ($_POST['fname'])`

Comment: `wondering if the rest of the code looks fine` - It's vulnerable to SQL Injection, so that's an issue. Check out "bound parameters".

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error - missing closing parenthesis:

```
if (isset ($POST_fname) {
```

Should be

```
if (isset ( ..... ) ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the ) everywhere after isset and didn't put semicolons after "AND". Here is the fixed file:

```
<?php
require_once('model.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE";

if (isset ($POST_fname)) {
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $query = $query . " fname = '" . $fname . "' AND";
}
if (isset ($POST_lname)) {
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $query = $query . " lname = '" . $lname . "' AND";
}

if (isset ($POST_age)) {
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        $query = $query . " age = '" . $age . "' AND";
}

if (isset ($POST_city)) {
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $query = $query . " city = '" . $city . "' AND";
}

$query = rtrim($query, " AND");
?>
<div id=/"header/">
<h1><strong>This is the information you requested</h1></strong>
</div>
<div id=/"main/">
<?php
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$products = $statement->fethAll();
$statement->closeCursor();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product['fname'] . " " . $product['lname'] . " | " . $product['age'] . " | " . $product['city'] . '<br />';
}
?>
</div>
<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: New error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\testwebpage\Model\getinformation.php on line 36'  Which is the last line of the file

Comment: I found one of the problems, I didnt end the foreach loop, so I put a closing bracket, but now I get the error Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\testwebpage\Model\getinformation.php on line 27

Comment: @jordankoal seems, that something is wrong with the query and $db->prepare returns false instead of an object

Comment: @jordankoal Probably, you don't enclose your string query parameters into quotes. Try my updated answer, I fixed the foreach '}' as well and added the quotes for every param. If it doesn't work, print $query before prepare and show me, what it gives

Comment: @jordankoal It would be even better, if you quote the query params after you get them from $_POST

Comment: OK, I correct a few more things.  $db was suppose to be $dbc because thats what I named it in my model.php.  Also, I took out the / that were in the header and main divs.  After that I get the error  Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\testwebpage\Model\getinformation.php on line 33

Comment: @jordankoal print $query before calling prepare and show it to me.

Comment: It showed SELECT * FROM people WHERE    so I went up and echoed out the $fname variable after it was set and it said the variable was undefined.  So it means they aren't getting passed over OR the isset isn't working right?

Comment: @jordankoal Yes, you receive no variables from POST, your SQL becomes invalid and fails.

Comment: I think my isset isn't working correctly.  I took out the if statment and just put $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $query = $query . " fname = '" . $fname . "' AND";   Now it displays the contents of $fname and the $query string was updated correctly.

Comment: @jordankoal Right, it should be if (isset ($_POST['fname']) and not if (isset ($POST_fname)). Can you accept my answer? I think it's good.

Comment: Yes, the query now updates correct.  It is having a problem with my fetchAll.   Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll() in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\testwebpage\Model\getinformation.php on line 35

Comment: @jordankoal There is no such method in mysqli_stmt class use fetch with while instead

Comment: Hmmm Ok.  THanks.  I'll have to figure out how to do that.. :)  Thanks for all the help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Forgot the ( at end of the if. look at the line 6 as said in the error output.

Answer (score 0):

(isset ($POST_fname)
be carfull
isset() is a expression that have 2 parenteses"(" ")" you opened, but din't close.

on every 'if' do this

```
if(isset(anything))
```

any other problem, come here !

Comment: New error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\testwebpage\Model\getinformation.php on line 36'  Which is the last line of the file